# How can I run cron in Docker? (No jobs/output even with simple crontab)

Tags: python, docker, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to put a cronjob inside my docker container, which runs a python script.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
ADD . /dir
WORKDIR /dir
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod 0644 /dir
ADD crontab /dir
ENV NAME loader
CMD  cron -f
```

My crontab file:

```
* * * * * root /loader.py
```

As i run:

```
$ docker run -t -i loader:latest
```

I get nothing even after 10 mins. The script writes out Hello world when it runs. I removed the cron  from the docker image and the script works and writes out Hello world

As I was trying to simplify things i tried to leave the script out so the cron only writes out something like hi every minute like this:

```
* * * * * root echo "hi"
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: `cron` won't be looking in `/CEEGEX/crontab` for its configuration. Install the file as `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so it should be ADD crontab CEEGEX/crontab?

Comment: `ADD crontab /etc/crontab`, rather. `/CEEGEX/crontab` is the thing you're doing now (that isn't working).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so `ADD crontab  /etc/crontab` doesnt work either, the crontab file is next to the script and dockerfile

Comment: *shrug*. Adjust syntax as appropriate -- if I were testing something to work, it'd be an answer, not a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.

First, as @charlesduffy mentioned, you need to install your `crontab` file where `cron` will find it (for example, `/etc/crontab`).  For testing purposes, I used the following `crontab` file:

```
* * * * * root date > /tmp/flagfile
```

I built an image using your `Dockerfile`, but I added a syslog service to see the log messages from `cron`.  My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron busybox
ADD . /dir
WORKDIR /dir
RUN chmod 0644 /dir
COPY crontab /etc/crontab
ENV NAME loader
CMD  busybox syslogd && cron -f
```

Once the container is running, I see the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Dec 11 19:49:54 1d77fad4bf9d cron.info cron[9]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Dec 11 19:49:54 1d77fad4bf9d cron.info cron[9]: (*system*) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/crontab)
Dec 11 19:49:54 1d77fad4bf9d cron.info cron[9]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

It looks like `cron` is unhappy with the permissions on `/etc/crontab`.  I modified my `Dockerfile` to fix that:

```
FROM python:3.6.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron busybox
ADD . /dir
WORKDIR /dir
RUN chmod 0644 /dir
COPY crontab /etc/crontab
RUN chmod 600 /etc/crontab
ENV NAME loader
CMD  busybox syslogd && cron -f
```

Now if I run the container, after about a minute I see `/tmp/flagfile` show up, and in `/var/log/messages` I see:

```
Dec 11 19:57:16 dda8a21d48a4 cron.info cron[10]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Dec 11 19:57:16 dda8a21d48a4 cron.info cron[10]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Dec 11 19:58:01 dda8a21d48a4 authpriv.err CRON[71]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Dec 11 19:58:01 dda8a21d48a4 authpriv.info CRON[71]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 11 19:58:01 dda8a21d48a4 cron.info CRON[72]: (root) CMD (date > /tmp/flagfile)
Dec 11 19:58:01 dda8a21d48a4 authpriv.info CRON[71]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I have a problem "installing" crontab on my windows so can you help me out with that?

Comment: `/tmp/flagfile`, in my example, is created by the cron job (`* * * * * root date > /tmp/flagfile`). It creates a file named `flagfile` inside the `/tmp` directory of the container. This was just an example to demonstrate that the cron job was executing. I'm not sure what you're asking in your first comment, so if you could maybe clarify the question I would be happy to help out.

Comment: yeah i was being stupid nevermind that. Right now im trying to ssh connect to the container to figure out whats missing, because if i copy everything you did nothing changes

Comment: so i manage to exec into the container and the crontab exist but still nothing shows up

Comment: I run the image and `docker logs loader` gives back nothing (the actuall cmd is `docker logs angry_hoover` because of container names)